# jQuery scrollTo plugin does not take "over" argument into account

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto

These two lines scroll to exactly the same place (the left side of the target element)

`$("#gallery").stop().scrollTo(thisP, 400, {offset:{top:0, left:-$(window).width()/2}}, {over:0.5});`

`$("#gallery").stop().scrollTo(thisP, 400, {offset:{top:0, left:-$(window).width()/2}});`

Note: `#gallery` is a div with a horizontal scrollbar, and `thisP` is an element contained inside that div

The documentation says {over:0.5} should cause it to scroll to the center of the target, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried {over: {top:0, left:0}}, and changing the order of offset and over, but it still doesn't scroll to the middle of the target. :<

Comment: [The documentation doesn't say that](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTo/)?

Comment: @Scimonster I'm talking about the jQuery plugin [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), not the function `scrollTop`.

Comment: Oh, ok. Didn't realize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrollTo` function takes only three arguments, the third one is an object, containig properties. That's why fourth argument is just ignored.
Try to do this:

```
$("#gallery").stop().scrollTo(thisP, 400, {offset:{top:0, left:-$(window).width()/2}, over:0.5});
```